# jquery AutoComplete textbox populate value with respect to Seleted value of Dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How can i populate my jQuery Autocomplete text box with respect to Selected Value of Dropdownlist from database in asp.net .I want to show value in autocomplete as per dropdownlist selection.here is my code when i select value in dropdownlist it can't invoke the webservice i don't know where i done wrong and how can i call service on dropdown selectindexchange event

```
var ddl = document.getElementById('<%=cmbSourceCode.ClientID %>');
$(function () {

    $("[id$=txtCode]").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("xCreate_grn.aspx/GetSourceCode") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "','code':'"+ddl.SelectedIndex+ "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 4,
        focus:function(event,ui){
          event.preventDefault();
          this.value = ui.item.label;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: `[id$=txtCode]` => are you sure this is a right selector? Have you getting errors in console & checking network tab to ensure the request resolved by target URL?

Comment: i can't get any error in console

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem,I pass selected value of drop down wrongly so my function not working now its working fine after using this in my code

```
$("[id$=txtCode]").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("xCreate_grn.aspx/GetSourceCode") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "','code':'"+ 
                          $('select[id=cmbSourceCode]').val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('~')[0],
                            val: item.split('~')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 4,
        focus:function(event,ui){
          event.preventDefault();
          this.value = ui.item.label;
        }

        }
    });
});
```